# How to create objects with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object

I'm currently working on a web page where you can add many different "machines" and then specify certain things about each one.

My original thought was to create div's for each machine (which would contain common elements like "name", "operating system", etc), and then change the IDs according to the names.  That being said, is this really the best approach?  Is there some way to use javascript/jquery to essentially make classes?

I also read briefly about some javascript template libraries like mustache, but did not get too into them.

Not looking for you to write the code for me -- just wondering how I should approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an array of [JSON objects](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) for this.

A Javascript library that supports model binding like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) can make displaying all the "machines" very easy with their foreach functionality.